# Nested Execution Flow Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've read tens of answers related to callbacks, promises and other ways to control flow, but I can't still wrap my head around this task, obviously due to my lack of competence.

I have a nested problem:

1. In `test_1()` (and the other functions) I would like to ensure that the rows are added to the table according to the order in which the elements are in the object;
2. I would like to execute either test_2 or test_3 (or both after each other) only after test_1 has finished completely. Actually the right sequence will only be known at runtime (there will be a switch with the possible sequences, like 1,2,3 or 1,3,2 or 1,2,1,3 or 1,3,3,2, etc...)

Code:

```
$(function () {

        // create table
        tbl = document.createElement('table');
        tbl.className = "mainTbl";
        $("body").append(tbl);    

    });

    function test_1() {
            $.each(obj, function () {
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
                };

                img.onerror = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
                };

                img.src = this.url;
            });
    }

function test_2() {
            $.each(obj, function () {
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
                };

                img.onerror = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
                };

                img.src = this.url;
            });
    }
function test_3() {
            $.each(obj, function () {
                var img = new Image();

                img.onload = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
                };

                img.onerror = function () {
                    // add row of data to table
                    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                    var c1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
                };

                img.src = this.url;
            });
    }
```

I know that calling the functions in sequence doesn't work as they don't wait for each other... I think promises are they way to go but I can't find the right combination and the documentation is way too complex for my skills.

What's the best way to structure the code so that it's executed in the right order?

Comment: this code all looks pretty synchronous to me, can you point out why it would act asynchronously

Comment: @RossBille - the rows are insert when in the image's onload handler which is asynchronous.

Comment: If you inserted the rows immediately and then just let the images load, you wouldn't have an asynchronous issue.  The async issue is caused because you're inserting the rows only when the images load.

Comment: It's possible to store all the intermediate results and only add the rows in sequential order regardless of what order the images load in while preserving the parallel loading of the iamges and it's possible to do all that with promises, but it seems like a lot of work for something that could probably be rethought into a simpler solution.  But, we'd have to know more about the actual requirements of what you're doing to be able to move up to a higher level of thinking about a better solution for you.

Comment: Also, why are `test_1()`, `test_2()` and `test_3()` identical code?

Comment: @jfriend00 So add rows first and then add the cells later. Clever! But `test_2` is still firing before `test_1` has finished (the actual functions are different but I didn't want to complicate the question). How to make it wait, keeping in mind that I can't hard-code a call to it from `test_1`?

Comment: So many questions ... Where is the code that calls the test_ functions? What is `obj`, the object that is looped through with `.each()`? Is `obj` the same object in every call of the test functions? Are the images appended to the document? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made this question very difficult to answer because your code is so abstract and tons of relevant details are missing such as how you call `test_1()` and `test_2()`, etc..., what you're doing with the images, what `obj` is, etc...  I know you tried to simplify things by leaving out detail, but really you just made it too abstract to know how to answer or what problem you're really trying to solve.

In JS, you can't call something and tell it to wait until something else is done.  You can tell `test_2()` when `test_1()` is done.  Or, you can register a sequence of functions and any time any `test_n()` is done, it can call the next function in the sequence.  Or, you could switch to using promises and use the promise functionality for scheduling async things to run in sequence.

In the spirit of your abstract discussion, here's an abstract way of sequencing things.  I've made two main changes:

1. The rows and cells are added synchronously as you iterate the `obj` so that guarantees that they are added in the proper order.
2. The separate functions are scheduled and `test_2()` isn't called until all functions scheduled before it have finished.  This is orchestrated without calling specific function names by creating a sequenced list of functions and then having each function use `seq.increment()` and `seq.decrement()` to let the sequencer keep track of when it's done so the next function can be called.

My guess is that an actual implementation doesn't have to be this generic and a more specific solution could be simpler, but since you've kept the discussion very abstract, this is a specific way to get the rows inserted in order and an abstract way to make sure the functions are called in order and `test_2()` isn't called until all the images have finished from `test_1()`.

```
// an object to maintain a list of functions that can be called in sequence
// and to manage a completion count for each one
function Sequencer() {
    this.list = [];
    this.cnt = 0;
}

Sequencer.prototype.add = function(/* list of function references here */) {
    this.list.push.apply(this.list, arguments);
}

Sequencer.prototype.next = function() {
    var fn = this.list.shift();
    if (fn) {
        fn(this);
    }
}

Sequencer.prototype.increment = function(n) {
    n = n || 1;
    this.cnt += n;
}

// when calling .decrement(), if the count gets to zero
// then the next function in the sequence will be called
Sequencer.prototype.decrement = function(n) {
    n = n || 1;
    this.cnt -= n;
    if (this.cnt <= 0) {
        this.cnt = 0;
        this.next();
    }
}

// your actual functions using the sequencer object
function test_1(seq) {
    seq.increment();
    $.each(obj, function () {
        seq.increment();
        var img = new Image();
        var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        var c1 = row.insertCell(0);

        img.onload = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.onerror = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.src = this.url;
    });
    seq.decrement();
}

function test_2(seq) {
    seq.increment();
    $.each(obj, function () {
        seq.increment();
        var img = new Image();
        var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        var c1 = row.insertCell(0);

        img.onload = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.onerror = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.src = this.url;
    });
    seq.decrement();
}

function test_3(seq) {
    seq.increment();
    $.each(obj, function () {
        seq.increment();
        var img = new Image();
        var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
        var c1 = row.insertCell(0);

        img.onload = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.onerror = function () {
            // add row of data to table
            c1.innerHTML = "not loaded";
            seq.decrement();
        };

        img.src = this.url;
    });
    seq.decrement();
}

// code to run these in sequence
var s = new Sequencer();

// add all the functions to the sequencer
s.add(test_1, test_2, test_3);

// call the first one to initiate the process
s.next();
```

FYI, I would personally never have code test_1, test_2 and test_3 that looks so nearly identical as I would factor it into a common piece that I could pass arguments to, but you've made this abstract so I don't know how to factor something you haven't provided any differences or specifics on.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. And sorry for the "keeping it simple" trouble... Took me a while to appreciate all the reasoning behind this solution. It's really smart. Thanks!

Comment: After applying this to the actual code, I noticed that from time to time it still skips to the next function without waiting for the current one to finish. It seems like `test_1`'s outer `seq.decrement()` gets fired before the first inner `seq.decrement` has a change to fire. I added a 1 sec timeout to the outer `seq.decrement()` and it does the trick, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @chris - something is wrong - no timer should be needed.  The outer `seq.decrement()` is supposed to fire before the inner ones do.  The inner ones come last when the images finish loading.  Can you show me your code and explain when it is not working for you?

Comment: here is the code: http://pastebin.com/eyGYfEh3 The script will attempt downloading tiny img files from nasty websites to understand if they are accessible (as a way to test pr0n blockers and the likes). So I apologize if you see connections to those sites...

Answer (score 1):

Chris, I see you have an answer but there are other ways to do this kind of thing, notably to write your `test_` functions such that they return a promise of all images having loaded or not loaded, and to exploit these promises to effect an asynchronous sequence.

Ideally we would have a `$.allSettled()` method available to us but as jQuery doesn't have such, we need a workaround. Fortunately the workaround is very simple in this case.

For compactness, I exploit jQuery as much as possible and end up with the following :

```
$(function () {
    var $tbl = $('<table class="mainTbl"/>').appendTo("body");
    function test_1() {
        //First, use $.map() to build an array of promises from `obj`.
        var promises = $.map(obj, function() {
            return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
                var $c1 = $("<td/>").appendTo($("<tr/>").prependTo($tbl));//a concise one-liner to make the required table elements and insert them in the DOM 
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = dfrd.resolve;//a jQuery Deferred's resolve method is "detachable"
                img.onerror = dfrd.reject;//a jQuery Deferred's reject method is "detachable"
                img.src = this.url;
            }).then(function() {//the workaround for lack of an allSettled method is to return a resolved promise from both the done and fail callbacks of a .then() .
                $c1.html("loaded");
                return $.when(1);//a resolved promise (resolved with 1, though it's not used)
            }, function() {
                $c1.html("not loaded");
                return $.when(0);//a resolved promise (resolved with 0, though it's not used)
            });
        });
        //Now return a new promise, which will be resolved when all images are "settled" (loaded state or  error state).
        return $.when.apply(null, promises);
    }

    function test_2() {
        // identical to test_1(), or a variant as required
    }
    function test_3() {
        // identical to test_1(), or a variant as required
    }

    // Now, build your sequence(s) as array(s). The exact way in which you do this will depend on your application.
    var sequence = [test_1, test_2, test_1, test_3];//some arbitrary sequence of functions, each of which, when executed, will return a promise. 

    // To run the seqnence, you simply exploit `array.reduce()` to build and execute a `.then()` chain, as follows :
    sequence.reduce(function(promise, fn) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            return fn();
        });
    }, $.when());

});
```

*all untested*

Since the advent of `.reduce()`, this is rapidly becoming the *de facto* solution to this type of problem and maybe more like what you originally envisaged. That's the essence of it anyway. In practice, the code may well be slightly more complicated, for example :

- if you need to pass paramters to the test_ functions
- if you need to handle errors

**Final Note**: A javascript object is an orderless collection of properties. If order *within* your `obj` is important, then use an array of elements, not an object of properties.

Comment: One issue with jQuery's `$.when()` is that it does a fail of the master promise as soon as the first promise given to `$.when()` fails.  It does not wait for all of them to be done and then communicate the fail status.  So, if one image fails here, the following function calls may start before the other images load in the previous function.  This binary behavior of `$.when()` reduces it's usefulness for many types of desired error handling (in my opinion).

Comment: @jfriend00, yes of course, that is precisely how `$.when()` is designed to work but it's not even remotely an issue. `$.when()` is used in two ways here. Firstly the expressions `$.when()`, `$.when(1)` and `$.when(0)` are guaranteed to generate resolved promises. Secondly, in the expression `$.when.apply(null, promises)`, `promises` is an array of Promises that are guaranteed to be resolved; as a workaround for the lack of a `.allSettled()` method, the expression never sees an error.

Comment: Thanks, nice alternative. This is what I had in mind, although jfriend00's solution is easier to understand, at least for me. But the way you presented it makes it very clear and useful. Thanks
!

Comment: Easier to understand! I think the jury is out on that one.